# how do I check how many int digits are inside and reset it to zero?

Tags: c++

I need to do the same but the variable `gram` can be any other number but no more or less than 3 characters.

I also need to immediately reset `n` if the `if` condition is met

```
int gram = 123, n = 0; // gram = 241, gram = 333, gram 512. etc

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    n = 1000 * n + gram;

    if (n == 123123123) // <--- here I don't know how to write a check
    {

        std::cout << " true:  " << n << std::endl;

        n = 0;
    }

    std::cout << n << std::endl;

}
```

I was able to do this

```
    int tik++;
    if (tik % 3 == 2) // But I don't like that the number tik keeps increasing.
    {

        std::cout << " true:  " << n << std::endl;

        n = 0; // <-- I want to get rid of that too
        tik = 0; // <-- I want to get rid of that too
    }
```

there is another question how to reverse the order of adding numbers to the variable `n`
I want to add not back but ahead.

```
 n = 1000 * n + gram;
```

Comment: *how do I check how many int digits are inside* - inside of what?

Comment: the question is rather unclear. Numbers with 3 digits are `x > 99 && x < 1000` and to "reset" `n` you do `n = 0;` is that not what you want?

Comment: @idclev463035818 not what I do suits me I only need conditions inside `if` to define any combination of digits
my example only checks one combination.

Comment: Please provide several examples of input with desired result. E.g. what do you want for -12, 98, 99, 100, 567, 999, 1000, 1001, 0x1, 070?

Comment: combinations of what? I suppose you refer to `if (n == 123123123)` but it is not clear how that relates to "check how many digits `gram` has"

Comment: I'm sure the question is quite simple actually.

Comment: I *think* you're looking for `if(i % 3 == 2)` which would give the same output. The question might be simple but it's not very clear.

Comment: If you as the author think a question is simple,but many people answer "What?", it usually means you should rephrease. Often using more words, clearer sentences and many examples helps.

Comment: @GuyIncognito that's fine thank you

Comment: I don't understand at all what you're asking and it seems like others does not either. Saying that the question is simple to people who don't understand it but are trying to help you will not help you getting the problem solved. So please do as we asked and provide example input and output.

Comment: Furthermore, use correct tags. `std::cout` is definitely not C.

Comment: Please phrase your question clearer. We all cant understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know `gram` is precisely three digits, given your multiply by `1000` and add approach, you can just have an inner loop that runs precisely three times, or a test for `i % 3 == 2` to reuse information from the outer loop's loop variable.

If the value isn't fixed, and you need to stop at or above `9` digits, just use [the `log10` family of functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log10) and trigger on the result being `>= 8.0` (`log10` of `100,000,000` is `8.0`; `log10` is a convenient way to count digits in base 10).

Comment: log10 and friends return floating point and are likely to disappoint.

Comment: @Yunnosch: In this case, it doesn't matter. They just need to know if it's `>= 8.0`, which even the devilry that is floating point gets right; `log10(100000000)` is `8.0`, `log10(100000000 - 1)` is `7.999999995657055`. They're not using it for further math, so floating point imprecision doesn't come into play; `log10` works just fine here.

Comment: can you show an example in my code?

Comment: @Fibl: Changing your `if` check to either `if (i % 3 == 2) {` or `if (n && std::log10(n) >= 8.0) {` would be minimal changes to achieve your desired end result. The latter handles variable length `gram` (with variable length multiplication, not just fixed `1000`), but if that's not needed, the former is simplest.

Comment: another question is does this code work faster?

Comment: @Fibl: Your original code (comparing to a constant) is about the cheapest test possible. My replacements will be slightly slower. That said, we're talking about a difference of a few dozen cycles at most (assuming the compiler isn't smart enough to spot the pattern and either unroll the loop or replace the test with a fixed interval between resets); on modern CPUs, you might "waste" a handful of nanoseconds (noise in the I/O you're performing).

Comment: Thank you, I did this, `if (log10(n) >= 8.0)` I think it would be more correct

Comment: I just don't understand why you added `n &&`

Comment: @Fibl: `log10(0)` triggers an error (there is no exponent of `10` which produces `0`, so taking the logarithm of `0` is nonsensical), so testing `n` first avoids the case where `log10` would error out. Not strictly necessary in your current design (where the test occurs after adding in a non-zero value), but I'm a little paranoid sometimes. :-) You'd need to test `n > 0` or use `log10(abs(n))` if negatives are a possibility.